# Как загрузить дополнительные файлы после установки приложения Android Studio?

Tags: android

Как можно загрузить дополнительные файлы ( аудио, видео, картинки ) после установки приложения и в дальнейшем использовать эти файлы в приложении. Есть примеры реализации или же статья который Вы знаете ?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду статичные ресурсы, которые не будут меняться после того, как они будут загружены на устройство? Тогда просто складывайте их в папки ресурсов приложения андроид, во время сборки они упакуются в apk.

Comment: Если вам нужно делать это динамически: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись, но вопрос заключается в том, что надо загрузить дополнительные файлы после установки приложения и потом использовать их в приложении. Например: есть обучающее приложение и вышла новая статья и надо показать уведомления о том что добавился новая статья и предложить загрузить и потом что бы читать ОФЛАЙН.

Comment: Ссылочку во втором комменте посмотрите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статья, в которой описывается как записать и прочесть файл с SD: [тык](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/138-urok-75-hranenie-dannyh-rabota-s-fajlami.html).

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо!